# Jquery not setting content with html()

Tags: jquery

Here's the hidden div

```
<div id="invited_div" style="display: none">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="e_relation"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here's jquery code

```
let tr = $('#invited_div').html();
$(tr).find('td.e_relation').html("Hello World");
console.log($(tr).find('td.e_relation')[0].outerHTML);
```

When I check console I only see

```
<td class="e_relation"></td>
```

Text is not getting set in the td element.

Comment: It is a typo, you are setting `tr` to the value of `html` not the div. Just remove `.html()` from the `let tr` line

Comment: And then, `tr` will already be a jQuery object, so no need to lookup again. That will be `tr.find(...)`

Comment: It worked. Thanks.